# Perfect algebraic spaces on a paper of Xinwen Zhu

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-spaces

I have problem reading Xinwen Zhu's paper [Affine Grassmannians and the geometric Satake in mixed characteristic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.8519v3) about perfect algebraic spaces in Section A.1.

Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$. A scheme (resp. an algebraic space) $X$ over $k$ is *perfect* if the Frobenius endomorphism $\sigma_{X}:X\rightarrow X$ is an isomorphism. The *perfection* of $X$ is the inverse limit $X^{p^{-\infty}}:=\lim_{\sigma_{X}}X$.

Here is Lemma A.2. that shows Frobenius endomorphisms commute with etale localizations.

> For any etale morphism of algebraic spaces $X\rightarrow Y$, the relative Frobenius
> morphism $X\rightarrow X\times_{Y,\sigma_{Y}}Y$ induced by $\sigma_{X}$ is an isomorphism.

However, how can this lemma proves the following two statements? I can't see any connection, especially the second statement.

> The tautological map $ε :X^{p^{-\infty}}\rightarrow X$ is a universal homeomorphism. $X$ is a scheme if and only if $X^{p^{-\infty}}$ is a scheme

Moreover, here is Lemma A.7:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of algebraic spaces over $k$, and let $f^{p^{-\infty}}:X^{p^{-\infty}}
> \rightarrow Y^{p^{-\infty}}$
> denote its perfection. The following properties hold for $f$ if and only if the
> same hold for $f^{p^{-\infty}}$: (6) affine.

I'm confused with the proof of (6). Why can we assume $Y$ to be affine by means of Lemma A.2? More precisely, why does Lemma A.2 show that one can reduce to the known affine case? I am very grateful if someone could explain my questions carefully.

Comment: Hi Toney, I don't currently have time to look at your questions in detail, but have you looked at the early sections of Bhatt-Scholze on the Witt vector affine Grassmannian (https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06490)? Also the early sections of my paper with Kevin Coulembier https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.05867 might contain more useful detail.

Comment: @Geordie Williamson: I have read Scholze paper before. But his paper is mainly focus on perfect schemes. I will read your paper carefully.